# How to fix this issue?

Tags: swift

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

//check popup in window frame

```
let spaceFromLeftSide = cutOutViewX.constant + cutOutViewWidth.constant/2 - (options.textWidth + padding*2)/2

let spaceFromRightSide = cutOutViewX.constant + cutOutViewWidth.constant/2 + (options.textWidth + padding*2)/2
```

Comment: `try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions` Well, I think it's often a good idea to follow the compiler's suggestions... ;)

Comment: How to fix the issue of _extremely bad question titles_, is explained in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that compiler not able to calculate value within time due to complex expression. You need to break these expressions into sub-expressions like this:

```
let cutOutValue = cutOutViewX.constant + cutOutViewWidth.constant/2
let optionsValue = (options.textWidth + padding*2)/2

let spaceFromLeftSide = cutOutValue - optionsValue
let spaceFromRightSide = cutOutValue + optionsValue
```

This type of breaking is not only helpful on compilation time but also helpful at debugging time where you can check the current value what variables have.